# How to grep csv file information and put it in another file

Tags: csv

I have a csv file. And I need to create another file out of it. The csv file is as follows

```
Signal Start,PK_SIG_NME,PK_SIGNALS_WIDTH,DESIGN_SIG_NME(exact string),, ,HRESETn   ,1,~dcc_ares,, ,HCLK,1,dcc_clk,, ,HADDR,              [31:0],i_dcc_qhs_haddr, etc
```

And the desired output is

```
.HRESETn(~dcc_ares), .HCLK(dcc_clk), .HADDR(i_dcc_qhs_haddr)
```

Comment: Cue @JacobVlijm - he loves this sort of challenge.

Comment: Does your file really have whitespace padding in the fields i.e. `,HRESETn       ,` rather than `,HRESETn,`?

Comment: Yes there are ...

Comment: Do not restrict yourself to `grep`.  `perl` has packages for dealing with CSV files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F"," '{ gsub (" ", "", $7); print "."$7"("$9"), ."$12"("$14"), ."$17"("$19")" }'
```

For n pattern

```
awk -F"," '{ gsub (" ", "", $7); for ( i = 1 ; i <=(NF-2) ; i++) if ( ((i - 7) % 5 ) == 0 && (i - 7) >= 0  )  printf "."$i"("$(i+2)"), "; print "" }'
```

Comment: Edited the answer make it general.

Answer (score 1):

For a better CSV support use `perl` and `Text::CSV`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({
    binary    => 1,
    auto_diag => 1,
    # uncomment the line below to avoid leading and trailing whitespaces
    allow_whitespace => 1,
    sep_char  => ','
});

while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    print ".$row->[6]($row->[8]), ";
    print ".$row->[11]($row->[13]), ";
    print ".$row->[16]($row->[18])\n";
}
close $fh;
```

Save the file as `./getit`, `chmod +x getit` and run with `./getit input.csv`

---

*Sample output*

```
.HRESETn(~dcc_ares), .HCLK(dcc_clk), .HADDR(i_dcc_qhs_haddr)
```

---

If you get an error message like this:

```
"use Text::CSV;" - Can't locate Text/CSV.pm
```

Install the right module via:

```
sudo apt-get install libtext-csv-perl
```

or

```
perl -MCPAN -e'install Text::CSV'
```

Comment: I am getting an error at line 5 "use Text::CSV;" - Can't locate Text/CSV.pm

Comment: @NarayananPM `sudo apt-get install libtext-csv-perl`, I have my answer improved.

Comment: I don't have the root permissions to do that. Is there any other way to put it in new file.

Comment: @NarayananPM That's a bigger problem. You should ask a new question for that. Sorry :\

Comment: @NarayananPM Ok, see my answer ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you ! Where can I find the answer

Comment: @NarayananPM `perl -MCPAN -e'install Text::CSV'` in my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with awk:

`awk 'BEGIN{RS=","} /HRESETn/||/HCLK/||/HADDR/{var=$0; printf "."var;getline;getline;printf "("$0")"; if(var != "HADDR") printf RS}' cvsfile.cvs`

**Explanation**

- treat comma as record separator.
- Find all the fields that are either HRESETn or HCLK or HADDR, print them
- print the second record after the matched string with curly braces around them.
- Check if HADDR was the last thing we printed, if it wasn't add coma at the end (this is to eliminate trailing comas)

**Output**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=","} /HRESETn/||/HCLK/||/HADDR/{var=$0; printf "."var;getline;getline;printf "("$0")"; if(var != "HADDR") printf RS}' cvsfile.cvs

.HRESETn   (~dcc_ares),.HCLK(dcc_clk),.HADDR(i_dcc_qhs_haddr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `python` solution :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/path/to/file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
       parts = line.split(',')
       print '.' + parts[6].rstrip() + '(' + parts[8] + ')' + ', .' + parts[11] + \
              '(' + parts[13] + ')' + ', .' + parts[16] + '(' + parts[18] + ')'
```

- This script will read the csv file line by line
- Then it will split the file to parts on `,` (`line.split(',')`)
- Then we have printed the required parts in desired format.

**Output :**

```
.HRESETn(~dcc_ares), .HCLK(dcc_clk), .HADDR(i_dcc_qhs_haddr)
```